# How to do fastScrolling on tablelayout in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, scroll, android-tablelayout

I have tableLayout filled with a lot of rows (in xml). I wrapped it in a scrollView and it scrolls great. However I'm trying to get the fastScrolling feature to work (the slider bar on the right) and saying `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"` for both the tableLayout and the scrollView does nothing. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is a simplified version of the layout code

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tableLayoutParent">
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout" android:fastScrollEnabled="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                    android:text="◦"
                    android:id="@+id/spaceColumn"
                    android:background="@drawable/top_button"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="showSlider"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="2dip"
                    android:textSize="15px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="15dip"/>
            <ToggleButton
                    android:textOn="Title ▼"
                    android:textOff="Title"
                    android:id="@+id/titleColumn"
                    android:background="@drawable/top_button"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="sortSong"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="2dip"
                    android:textSize="15px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"/>
            <ToggleButton
                    android:textOn="Artist ▼"
                    android:textOff="Artist"
                    android:id="@+id/artistColumn"
                    android:background="@drawable/top_button"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="sortArtist"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="2dip"
                    android:textSize="15px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"/>
            <ToggleButton
                    android:textOn="Time ▼"
                    android:textOff="Time"
                    android:id="@+id/timeColumn"
                    android:background="@drawable/top_button"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="sortTime"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="2dip"
                    android:textSize="15px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="45dip"/>
            <ToggleButton
                    android:textOn="Album ▼"
                    android:textOff="Album"
                    android:id="@+id/albumColumn"
                    android:background="@drawable/top_button"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="sortAlbum"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="2dip"
                    android:textSize="15px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"/>
        </TableRow>
     </TableLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

song data is then read from a SQLite database and filled into the table layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ScrollView doesn't support fast scroll out of the box as far as I know, what you are looking for is ListView.

Edit: Unless you implement it yourself ofcourse.

Comment: Ok I see that now thanks, but how can I use this with a tableLayout?

Comment: can you tell me about the structure of your table layout ?

Comment: thats a single row, thats easy just check this http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/